# What is the number of Mel Filters used in librosa MFCC function?

Tags: speech-recognition, librosa, mfcc

librosa.feature.mfcc(y=None, sr=22050, S=None, n_mfcc=20, dct_type=2, norm='ortho', lifter=0, **kwargs)

The librosa MFCC function does not contain an parameter to be passed for the number of mel filters to be used. Is there a way to define it or does it use the default value of '''n_mels=128''' used in librosa.filters.mel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mfcc function will pass additional keyword arguments to `librosa.feature.melspectrogram` as specified in the doc under `kwargs`.

> kwargs: additional keyword arguments
> Arguments to `melspectrogram`, if operating on time series input

If you go to [`melspectrogram`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html#librosa.feature.melspectrogram), you'll see it is again linked to `librosa.filters.mel` under `kwargs`.

> kwargs: additional keyword arguments
> Mel filter bank parameters.
> See `librosa.filters.mel` for details.

So, [`librosa.filters.mel`](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.filters.mel.html#librosa.filters.mel) is where you should check out for those parameters. This function has all the parameters you need here.

> `librosa.filters.mel(sr, n_fft, n_mels=128, fmin=0.0, fmax=None, htk=False, norm='slaney', dtype=<class 'numpy.float32'>)`

---

To summarize, you can pass parameters like `n_mels`, `fmin` and `fmax` or temporal parameters like `n_fft` (as defined in `librosa.filters.mel`) or `hop_length` (as defined in `librosa.features.melspectrogram`).

Comment: Will the defaults be the same as melspectrogram?

Comment: Yes, they are the same